# Ember filter a list by property name

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a an array coming from my model..

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'test1', created: true}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'test2', created: false}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'test3', created: true}
]
```

I am interested showing two lists. I created a component to show the list:

```
../components/created.hbs

<div>
  {{model.name}}
</div>
```

---

```
../main.hbs

<h2> Created true </h2>

{{#each}}
   {{created model=model }}
{{/each}}


<h2> Created false </h2>

{{#each}}
   {{created model=model }}
{{/each}}
```

The first list would show the the objects with the created property set to true and the second would show those with the created property set to false.

I was wondering if there was a simple way of doing the above in Ember as in Angular where you could use filter pipes inside the each block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` syntax in ember.js:

```
{{#each list as |item|}}
  do what you want with item...
{{/each}}
```

First option:

So you can write a [helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/templates/writing-helpers/) named `filterBy`, than use it:

```
{{#each (filterBy list key value) as |item|}}
  do what you want with item...
{{/each}}
```

Second option:

You can write a [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/computed-properties/) named `filteredList` in your component that uses [`Ember.computed.filterBy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filterBy) :

```
{{#each filteredList as |item|}}
  do what you want with item...
{{/each}}
```

Both is acceptable for ember.js. I generally prefer second one as it has the filtering function in the component and doesn't need another dependency.